# How to evenly intersperse one list into another?

Tags: python, list

I want to insert a shorter list into a longer one, at equal intervals.  For example, given

```py
# existing list
main_list = ['lst1','lst2','lst3','lst4','lst5','lst6'] 

# aux list to be inserted to main list
aux_list = ['ax1','ax2','ax3']
```

I want output to be

```py
# desired output list
new_list = ['lst1','lst2','ax1','lst3','lst4','ax2','lst5','lst6','ax3']
```

I tried

```py
new_list = [i[:2]+k for i,k in zip(main_list,aux_list)]
```

but this did not produce the desired output. (**EDITED FOR CLARITY**)

Comment: Is `len(main_list)` always a multiple of `len(aux_list)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's right. It is always multiple.

Comment: Please add expect output

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I mentioned it in my question `new_list`.

Comment: As you should have already noticed it's not clear. Please edit your question and mark that list clearly as example of desired output

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I edited my question. Clearly mentioned the desired output.

Comment: @Mainland: what is the logic of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `sum` with `zip`:

```
print(sum(zip(main_list[::2], main_list[1::2], aux_list), ()))
```

Output:

```
('lst1', 'lst2', 'ax1', 'lst3', 'lst4', 'ax2', 'lst5', 'lst6', 'ax3')
```

If you want the result to be a list use:

```
print(list(sum(zip(main_list[::2], main_list[1::2], aux_list), ())))
```

Output:

```
['lst1', 'lst2', 'ax1', 'lst3', 'lst4', 'ax2', 'lst5', 'lst6', 'ax3']
```

**Edit:**

Use this if you want it to work for all different lengths:

```
print(sum(zip(*[main_list[i::len(main_list) // len(aux_list)] for i in range(len(main_list) // len(aux_list))], aux_list), ()))
```

Output:

```
('lst1', 'lst2', 'ax1', 'lst3', 'lst4', 'ax2', 'lst5', 'lst6', 'ax3', 'lst7', 'lst8', 'ax4')
```

Again if you want the result to be a list, use:

```
print(list(sum(zip(*[main_list[i::len(main_list) // len(aux_list)] for i in range(len(main_list) // len(aux_list))], aux_list), ())))
```

Comment: How to write the same in terms of the main_list length and aux_list length?

Comment: @Mainland Edited mine, check it out don't forget to accept if it works

Comment: I did that. Don't mind: I have a quick question. How to re arrange`['lst1','lst3','lst5','lst2','lst4','lst6']` as `['lst1','lst2','lst3','lst4','lst5','lst6']` ? I mean Iactually have a 44 elements.

Comment: @Mainland Do you want them to be sorted, if so use `sorted(yourlist)`

Comment: But my actual list has names as elements. No values are associated with it. So, `sort` may  not work here.

Comment: @Mainland I suggest you to ask another question than, too hard too get it in the comments

Comment: Thanks. I posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471592/python-list-rearrange-the-elements-in-a-required-order

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe easier to follow, and scales with different list sizes:

```py
main_list = ['lst1','lst2','lst3','lst4','lst5','lst6'] 
aux_list = ['ax1','ax2','ax3'] 

# get subdivision sizes in main_list
m = len(main_list) // len(aux_list)

# create list of lists (in blocks)
z = [main_list[m*i:m*(i+1)] + [aux] for i,aux in enumerate(aux_list)]

# flatten
z = [k for sec in z for k in sec]

z
# ['lst1', 'lst2', 'ax1', 'lst3', 'lst4', 'ax2', 'lst5', 'lst6', 'ax3']
```

(Note this will give unexpected output and/or break if your lists are not divisible sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @U10-Forward's answer and generalizing it:

```
skip = len(main_list) // len(aux_list)
main_sub_lists = [main_list[i:i+skip] for i in range(0, len(main_list), skip)]
desired = sum([a_l + [b] for a_l, b in zip(main_sub_lists, aux_list)], [])
```

Comment: This just adds the new list at the last. But what I am expecting is something different.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't understand your question then. Please rephrase your question and I'll post an edit to my answer.