# Python list rearrange the elements in a required order

Tags: python

My main list has 44 names as elements. I want to rearrange them in a specific order. I am giving here an example. Note that elements in my actual list are some technical names. No way related to what I have given here.

```
main_list = ['one','two','five','six',.................'twentyone','three','four','seven','eight',.....,'fortyfour']
```

I want to rearrange the list. I have no idea how to proceed. But my expected output should like this
Expected output:

```
main_list = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight'.................'twentyone',,.....,'fortyfour']
```

Comment: First you must be able to explain the sorting rule (at least in plain English) or have prepared a list defining how they should be sorted.

Comment: Look at this: https://www.codespeedy.com/sort-list-of-list-with-custom-compare-function-in-python/ . Since this sounds iike a homework I won't give you an code example how to do that. If you've try something already and you have a error message or unexpected result. You can come back and ask help that.

Comment: `my actual list are some technical names`, like what?

Comment: `'vol1','cur','draf','mol','ext',.....` etc like this.

Comment: If you have access to `pandas`, you can use `pd.Categorical` to sort your items. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223256/pandas-dataframe-sort-by-categorical-column-but-by-specific-class-ordering) is a nice sample.

Comment: And how would you rearrange those examples?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You've barely even explained the operation you're trying to perform. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (this is just the first Google hit I found for something to convert English representations of numbers to integer values; whatever you use needs to be something that works to convert whatever your actual data is into something sortable): https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

```
from word2number import w2n

main_list.sort(key=w2n.word_to_num)
```

Or come up with your own cheesy version as appropriate to your data.  Taking your example you could do something like:

```
number_words = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'twenty': 20,
    'forty': 40,
    'sixty': 60,
}
def word_to_number(word: str) -> int:
    if word in number_words:
        return number_words[word]
    # Try chomping each number out of the word.
    for n in number_words:
        if word.endswith(n):
            return number_words[n] + word_to_number(word[:-len(n)])
    raise ValueError(f"I don't know what number '{word}' is!")
```

```
>>> main_list
['one', 'two', 'sixtyfour', 'five', 'six', 'twentyone', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'eight', 'fortyfour']
>>> sorted(main_list, key=word_to_number)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'twentyone', 'fortyfour', 'sixtyfour']
```

Comment: Note that this will raise a `ValueError: No valid number words found! Please enter a valid number word (eg. two million twenty three thousand and forty nine)` as it requires a specific format (i.e. it won't parse `twentyone`).

Comment: Wouldn't your second method fail for `sixtyone`, for example?

Comment: For the first method, you'd need to have a library that works with your particular numeric formatting; OP indicated this is just an example, so we don't know what exactly will work for their real life data.  For the second (where you roll it yourself), you need to add words to `number_words` until it works for your input, so you'd need to add `sixty: 60` for it to handle `sixtyone`.

Comment: It won't work even you append `sixty` to the dictionary, unless you insert it at a specific position. What I'm saying is that this method is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dictionary to use as your sorting key:

```
sort_keys = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'ten': 10,
    'twenty': 20,
}
main_list = ['twenty', 'one', 'three', 'ten', 'two']
main_list.sort(key=lambda i: sort_keys[i])
print(main_list)
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'ten', 'twenty']
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to sort number words in numeric order. But your examples above have poorly-formed words that need fixing, such as twentyone and fortyfour. This is one way you could address it.

```
from word2number import w2n

main_list = ['one', 'two', 'five', 'six', 'twentyone', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'eight', 'fortyfour']

VALID = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']

TENS = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

renamed = []

for item in main_list:
    if item in VALID or item in TENS:
        renamed.append(w2n.word_to_num(item))
    else:
       for num in TENS:
           one = item.split(num)[-1] 
           if one in VALID:
               renamed.append(w2n.word_to_num(f'{num} {one}'))
```

Output

```
>>>sorted(renamed)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 44]
```

Comment: The output does not match the expected output. Also the actual input has nothing to do with numbers written as words as indicated in comments.